# My Swedish residence permit is in processing and I therefore don't have a valid Schengen visa. Can I exit the Schengen area from a different country?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps

I have a residence permit for studying in Sweden and it ended on 1st of September, 2017. I applied for extending it before it ended so I have the right to stay in Sweden until I get the replay from migration.  But the migration considered me a first-time applicant as I changed my studies and they asked me to apply from outside of Sweden in order to be granted the new residence permit.

So now I want to go back to my home country in Africa in order to get the new one. But I have the issue that there is no direct flight from Sweden to my home country. So If I book a flight from Sweden to my home country through Denmark for example (as transit) and they asked me about my visa it will be considered overstayed and I will face a problem.

Could I get a stamp from Sweden before I go to Denmark? Or I should book a flight from Sweden to Turkey for example (as transit) in order to escape the overstay issue?

Comment: Good question.  In theory the Danish authorities should respect the fact that you are in compliance with Swedish law, but I am unaware of a specific law requiring it or of what their actual practice might be.  It's probably safer to fly through Istanbul or another non-Schengen country.  Can you clarify whether there is a document you should show at the Swedish border to demonstrate your situation?  Perhaps the Danish would accept that.

Comment: Denmark will not consider you to have overstayed since you have permission to live in Sweden.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk the permission expired a month and a half ago.

Comment: Thanks for paying attention. I have the right to stay in Sweden while waiting for decision. The case officer just sends me the receipt which shows that I applied for extending residence permit before the previous one is ended and that I have payed the money required for application at migration. That is the message from migration ""While it is correct that an applicant may be in Sweden while having a pending application for a residence permit, we wish to inform you that a general rule is that a first-time application cannot be granted while the applicant is in Sweden.""

Comment: The case officer said to me that I can fly from Sweden to my home country through Denmark. "Thus you will not cross any borders, just travel through airports" but I am afraid that I could face problems at Copenhagen airport as it will be last schengen country I will leave.

Comment: @phoog Is it not possible that the "a month and a half" period in Sweden gets regarded as traveling to Schengen countries with 90/180 rule? (given the assumption that the OP is from a country where Schengen visa is exempt and didn't get out of Sweden while the visa was valid)

Comment: Would flying through London be an option instead?

Comment: @Blaszard: The OP states they are from an African country, none of which are visa-free for Schengen. (Except if Mauritius and the Seychelles are counted as African, but neither of those have direct flights from Copenhagen, so it can't be them).

Comment: Would this question be better served in [expatriates.se] or would it be the same set of responders?

Comment: Fly via the Middle East?

Comment: I am from Egypt. I do not think that London would be an apllicable solution as it may needs a transit visa. I would rather prefer to travel to Turkey as a transit to avoid any possible issues at checkpoint in Copenhagen. It seems a more safe solution to me as I do not have any confirmed information about what would occur there. Or the other possible solution which I do not prefer, is to stay until I will get the refusal from migration. Then I have an official paper to travel safely and once I arrived to Cairo, I will appeal on decision but it would waste a lot of time.

Comment: I had a valid study visa from 1 August 2016 till 1 September 2017. I did not think that 90/180 schengen rule is applicable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a letter from the Swedish authorities certifying that you're OK in their eyes and will apply for an extension back in Nigeria, you should have no problems showing that and the expired residence permit.

Otherwise, to be safe, book a flight through the UK or Turkey (for example) as you'll then be checked by the Swedish authorities when leaving Schengen.